Google Ads API: gRPC Channel Maxed Out and searchStream() Call Failing in PHP
I'm working with the Google Ads API and trying to run the GetCampaigns.php example from the official repository. The authentication works fine, but when I try to execute the searchStream() method to retrieve campaigns, I get warnings about gRPC channels being maxed out, and the process stops.
This is the file
The error log shows the following:

WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1727872579.980136   22500 channel.c:277] [Warning] Target upper bound: 1. Current size: 1.
I0000 00:00:1727872579.980178   22500 channel.c:280] [Warning] Target googleads.googleapis.com:443 will not be persisted.



I tried debugging the code, and the execution stops at this line:
$stream = $googleAdsServiceClient->searchStream(
    SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest::build($customerId, $query)
);

I also tried increasing the number of gRPC channels by setting the following environment variable, but it didn't solve the issue:
putenv('GRPC_DEFAULT_MAX_CHANNELS=10');

I got the same error when I had a typo in one of the parameters, once I fixed it the request worked. Does it show any other error?
